# Search / Replace using key:values from file in bash?

Tags: bash

So I have a file of "keys", for example:

```
key1
key2
key3
```

and I have a file of key:value pairs:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
```

I want to replace the keys in my file of keys with their corresponding values in the key:value file. So the file of keys will look like this when complete:

```
value1
value2
value3
...
```

What is the best way to do this in bash? Note that a key may appear more than once in the keys file, but should only appear once in the key:values file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the join command is available in your environment, the following should work. The addition of an index via the awk command is needed to restore original key order (via a Schwartzian transform).

```
join -o 1.1,2.2 -t':' -1 2 -2 1 <(awk '{print(NR":"$0)}' key_file | sort -k2,2 -t':') <(sort -k1,1 -t':' key_values_file) | sort -k1,1 -t':' | cut -f2 -d':'
```

Comment: Not sure this is working the way I specified. My keys file has 67,683 entries. The file generated from this has 37,098 entries. I mentioned that a key may appear more than once in the keys file (and I want the corresponding value to appear exactly that number of times in the output).

Comment: My bad. I got a few files confused. :D Thanks, your answer works great!

Answer (score 0):

I know you want "bash" , but this is very simply solved with a quick perl script.  Assume you have the files `pairs.txt` and `keys.txt` :

```
use strict;
my %keys2values; 

# read through the pairs file to get the key:value mapping
open PAIRS, "cat pairs.txt |" ; 
while(<PAIRS>) { 
   chomp $_; 
   my ($key,$value) = split(":",$_); 
   $keys2values{$key} = $value; 
} 

open KEYS, "cat keys.txt |"; 
while(<KEYS>) { 
   chomp $_; 
   my $key = $_; 
   if(defined $keys2values{$key}) { 
      print "$keys2values{$key}\n"; 
   }
   # if a key:value pair isn't defined, just print the key
   else { 
      print "$key\n";  
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a thing for pure-bash solutions, I'll just post this solution. It will only work in bash 4+, because it uses associative arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read key value; do
    declare -A hash[$key]=$value
done < pairfile

while read key; do
    printf '%s\n' "${hash[$key]}"
done < keyfile
```

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing a few errors in your first loop, as I was about to post an identical solution.